# Cannot be resolved or is not a field with Android spinners

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I am trying to learn how to implement a simple spinner program to test how they work.  I am getting numerous errors on the R.ID portion and the R.Array values after them.  I get the error that they cannot be resolved or are not a field.  Not sure if the `<resource>`s belong in manifest.xml or the layout .xml.

Java code:

```
package com.example.androidassignment2_3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class Spinner extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_spinner);


        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.activity_android_spinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.spinner, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

layout xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidassignment2_3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2_3.Spinner"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added string array in manifest, it should be in your strings xml which is inside values folder.

Even remove it from layout xml and place it only once in strings xml

Your array adapter declaration looks good, as says its creating adapter from resource which has id R.array.planets_array this means that the adapter will look out for the array in strings xml.

Comment: makes sense to put it there.  Although I am still not able to successfully run the code as a problem is occuring in the layout xml

Answer (score 0):

your array values ​​spinner should be **res/values/string.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">SOR</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>
...
</resources>
```

[Android Array Resouces](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
```

instead of:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.activity_android_spinner);
```

Your spinners id is `planets_spinner`

Answer (score 0):

Change your class(Activity) name to `public class Spinner123 extends Activity {` or something else from `public class Spinner extends Activity {`.